# "Disable touchpad while typing" for under 1 second

Tags: 16.04, touchpad

I want to use the Option "Disable touchpad while typing" in the touchpad configuration(Settings->Mouse and Touchpad->Devices). It is working while using a value > 1sec. For my usage it seems way to long. When I try to use a value like 0.9 it doesn't work at all. Anyone knows a fix for this. I want to get like 0.5 or something similar.

Working with: Xubuntu 16.04

Touchpad: SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad on a HP Spectre

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to my described problem. You can call:

```
syndaemon -K -i 0.2 -R -d
```

For me works 0.2 seconds, but you can change the value to your desires.

I could not get it running over the settings configuration, but I added the syndaemon command to my startup commands and it works fine.